# Display image from an array based on a variable

Tags: php, arrays, list, country

Depending on the user's country, I want to load the flag image for the country thats stored in an array. Currently I only know the switch method, like so:

```
$countryFlags = array("afghanistan.png", "albania.png", "algeria.png", "andorra.png" ... );

// gets the user country from DB
$userCountry = $country['Country'];

switch($userCountry) {
    case "Australia":
        echo /* the image name from countryFlags array */ ; break;
    case "America":
        echo /* the image name from countryFlags array */ ; break;
    default:
        echo("Unknown");
}
```

.. but it'll take a while to write the conditions and I believe there must be a better way to do it?

Comment: Why not get rid of the array altogether, use the country's name, lowercase it (using `strtolower()`) and see whether a PNG of that name `file_exists()`?

Comment: @Pekka웃 hmm..but the names are not exact matches, some might be different, would it still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array with the country code as key, and the image URL as value:

```
$countryFlags = array();
$countryFlags['za'] = images/za.png;
$countryFlags['us'] = images/us.png;
// etc...

echo $countryFlags[$userCountryCode];
```

Comment: by the way, i love using sprites for the image flags, here's a great source for them ;) http://flag-sprites.com/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have control over the naming why not simply:

```
$userCountry = $country['Country'];

echo strtolower($userCountry) . ".png";
```

Giving it "America" in the commandline would provide `america.png` return.

If you can't do that construct your array as follows:

```
$countryFlags = array(
  "America" => "america.png",
  "Afganistan" => "afganistan.png",
  ...etc...
);

echo $countryFlags[$userCountry];
```

**EDIT::**

A mix & match of the above two

```
//Define list of countries that aren't a direct translation
$countryFlags = array(
  "Canada" => "cdn_flag.png",
  "Mexico" => "mexico.jpg",
);

if ( !in_array($userCountry,$countryFlags) ) {
  echo strtolower($userCountry) . ".png";
} else {
   echo $countryFlags[$userCountry];
}
```

Comment: hmm..but the names (coming from db and the filename) are not exact matches, some are different, it won't work then I suppose?

Comment: @Nimbuz use the second part of his answer in that case.

Comment: There're 275 names, I don't want to write it manually, thats the thing :)

Comment: If there is no naming convention between your db and .png files Array seems like the best option. How different are they ? Can you match them using regex ?

Comment: Yeah its an unfortunate truth where you either force a standard on the names so you can do a trick like #1 or similar or put the time in to write out your constant list that can be referenced later on.

Comment: Most of them have the same name, so you could write a one-time script to create the variable assignment, then fix up the ones that are different.

Comment: @Nimbuz I added an edit that shows how you could mix/match for countries that aren't easily translated like in option #1